# How to change MySQL 8.0 data folder. Can I use OneDrive folders?

Tags: mysql-8.0, my.ini

I'm trying to create a DataBase for a very little program that just I and 2 more friends use, so the database will be little.

What I want to do is to share this database with these 2 friends, so I thought about storing the data in a OneDrive shared folder.

At the moment, I'm using a txt file as a "database". Which is placed in a shared OneDrive folder, so when my friends execute the program, it can read the data from there and make it sort of real time "online".

The thing is that I can't find the my.ini file in my

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\
```

directory, so I can't change the data folder.

Another trouble I have is that I also don't have the Data folder in that directory, instead I've found it in this one:

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE
```

Is it possible to do what I want to do? And how should I proceed?

Do you think I should be using MySQL 5.x version?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Even if you can use OneDrive (or similar product), I would expect it to be a disaster waiting to happen.  Neither MySQL nor XyzDrive is designed to worry about fast, real-time, actions.  So, I would expect any network hiccup, or drive hiccup, or long network delay, etc, to risk a serious "disk" error being returned to MySQL, necessitating a crash.

Also, MySQL is *not* prepared to have *two* instances talking to the same files.  Will you really disconnect from one computer before connecting another??  The day you fail to do that is the day the data is corrupted beyond repair.

Even if XyzDrive *and* MySQL decide to make it a viable feature, performance would probably suck -- somewhere between 10x and 100x slower than a local drive, and somewhat slower than a remote drive.

(If I am wrong, please speak up.)